# Write a program that prompts the user to input a sequence of characters and outputs the numbers of vowels

Tags: java

```
  import java.util.*;

public class VowelCounter
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input a series of characters: ");
    String letters = keyboard.next();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++)
    {
        char characters = letters.charAt(i);
        if (isVowel(characters) == true)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number of vowels is: " + count);

  }
  public static boolean isVowel(char characters)
  {
    boolean result;
      if(characters=='a' || characters=='e' || characters=='i' || characters=='o' || characters=='u')
        result = true;
      else
        result = false;
    return result;
}
}
```

The code works but im suppose to input "Spring break only comes once a year." which if i do with the spaces my program will only find the vowels of Spring. how do i make it so it will skip the spaces and read the whole sentence.

Comment: Instead of using `String letters = keyboard.next();` use `keyboard.nextLine()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

```
String letters = keyboard.next();
```

The `Scanner` stops reading at the first whitespace.

To read the complete phrase until you press enter, you should use `nextLine()` instead:

```
String letters = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 9):

This is your problem:

```
String letters = keyboard.next();
```

It has nothing to do with the vowel-counting part - but everything to do with reading the value. The `Scanner.next()` method will only read to the end of the token - which means it stops on whitespace, by default.

Change that to

```
String letters = keyboard.nextLine();
```

and you should be fine.

You should verify this is the problem by printing out the string you're working with, e.g.

```
System.out.println("Counting vowels in: " + letters);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
String letters = keyboard.nextLine();
```

instead of

```
String letters = keyboard.next();
```

This is because .nextLine() will read line by line so that you can have your complete statement in latters. Hope this will help you